# Angular cli as frontend with backend python framework, how to make them work?

Tags: python, angular, tornado, angular-fullstack

My question is how data pass between Angular 4 and tornado(or any python framework?)

I have been doing googling for past few days, but I still could not figure out how it works.

I am using Angular4 as frontend framework. but I want to use python tornado as backend. How the data pass from frontend to backend and backend to frontend. How to make it works?

I hope I can have some useful example or explanation to help me understand it.

I found one demo using angular cli with Django, but I do not understand how they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not good with Python, but most of the time you will communicate from your SPA to your server through http calls (with a Rest API exposed from your server for example).

Hope that helps